# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
if (isset($_POST['pf1'])) {
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE t1
                SET pref1 = :pf1, 
                WHERE id = 1 ");
        $stmt->bindParam(':pf1', $_POST['pf1']);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "pf1";

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It gives error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

I want to update data to db. But it gives me error of PDO exception.

I don't know what's the issue is any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What should `echo $stmt`  do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be because it ends up in your `catch`.

It then says `echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();`.
You are trying to echo $stmt (being an Object of class PDOStatement). You cannot echo an Object.

Try `var_dump($stmt);` to check if the above is true. If that's the case, simply remove the `echo` of `$stmt` and you should be good.